# Alternative to REPLACE INTO TABLE mysql query

Tags: mysql, replace

I usually copy data into tabelB from table A daily by the following query:

```
REPLACE INTO tableB (id,col1,col2,col3) SELECT id,col1,col2,col3 FROM tableA WHERE date='somedate'
```

Here REPLACE is used as if the script is being run double for a particular date by mistake, it will not copy the tableA two times into tableB. But problem is, tableB has two unique key index (id and col1). So if REPLACE is executed more than once, index is deleted and recreated by this REPLACE command. To avoid this thing, I want to use:

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id,col1,col2,col3) VALUES (val1,val2,val3,val4) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2=VALUES(col2),col3=VALUES(col3)
```

But as I am copying the tableA here, I cant use the above INSERT........ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query, I have to use SELECT command to copy data from tableA.

So how to modify INSERT INTO ........... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query, so that it can copy the tableA and at the same time if execute the script more than once, it just updates the data.

Regards

Comment: did you see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this INSERT query -

```
INSERT INTO tableB (id, col1, col2, col3)
  SELECT id, col1, col2, col3 FROM tableA WHERE date = 'somedate'
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col2 = VALUES(col2), col3 = VALUES(col3);
```